# Invalid Credentials google Calendar API

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-api, google-calendar-api

I try to insert event to google calendar

**Code below :**

```
func insertEventToGoogleCalendar() {
    Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true, completion: { (idToken, error) in
        if let err = error {
            self.unknownError(error: err)
        } else {
            let documentData: [String: Any] = ["end": ["dateTime": "2019-06-07T17:00:00-07:00"],
                                               "start": ["dateTime": "2019-06-07T17:00:00-07:00"],
                                               "description": "test",
                                               "summary": "test"]
            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/\(CALENDARID)/events")!)
            let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: documentData, options: [])
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = jsonData
            request.addValue("Bearer \(idToken!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    self.unknownError(error: err)
                }
                if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print(response.statusCode)
                }
                if let data = data {
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    })
}
```

What am I missing or what is missing in my code? I get an error from google:

```
Optional("{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"authError\",\n    \"message\": \"Invalid Credentials\",\n    \"locationType\": \"header\",\n    \"location\": \"Authorization\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 401,\n  \"message\": \"Invalid Credentials\"\n }\n}\n")
```

Comment: Have you set your OAuth scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`?

Comment: @jess Not do. How to do it?

Comment: @jess can you help me?